# Ошибка: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Tags: javascript

Выдается ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Код js:

```js
function create() {

 function getRandom() {
  return Math.round(Math.random()*(mainArr.length-1))
 }
 

 currentFigure = getRandom();

 figureBody = [
  document.querySelector('[posX = "${x}"][posY = "${y}"]'),
  document.querySelector('[posX = "${x + mainArr[currentFigure][0][0]}"][posY = "${y + mainArr[currentFigure][0][1]}"]'),
  document.querySelector('[posX = "${x + mainArr[currentFigure][1][0]}"][posY = "${y + mainArr[currentFigure][1][1]}"]'),
  document.querySelector('[posX = "${x + mainArr[currentFigure][2][0]}"][posY = "${y + mainArr[currentFigure][2][1]}"]'),
 ]

 for (let i = 0; i < figureBody.length; i++) {
  figureBody[i].classList.add('figure');
 }
}
```

Comment: Замените `'` на `.

Comment: Всё равно не выходит

Comment: Ответ - внизу. Все выходит.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените `'` на `:

```
document.querySelector(`[posX="${x}"][posY="${y}"]`),
```

и так далее.

```js
var x = 1;
var y = 2;
console.log(document.querySelector('[posX="${x}"][posY="${y}"]'));
console.log(document.querySelector(`[posX="${x}"][posY="${y}"]`));
```

```html
<div id="test" posX="1" posY="2">TEST</div>
```